# iOS app crashes while opening in device Unity?

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I'm using Unity version `2018.3.14f`. I'm using `vuforia(8.1)` with it. Everything is working fine. I'm able to test my project from Unity Editor. The problem arises when I export it to `iOS`. When I build I get issue of

> 'release' is unavailable: not available in automatic reference
>   counting mode

So I set the `Object reference counting` to `no`. And the error gone away.

Build also succeeds but when I run on a real device I get error `UnityGfxDeviceWorker EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. The build installs on device but when Opens it crashes in a second.

Logs are here

[image]

What is I'm doing wrong here? Please suggest me. 
These are my player settings:

[image]
[image]

Comment: In the iOS settings, does your app have all required permissions? Usually the OS would kill apps trying to access hardware it has no permissions to.

Comment: Yes. I'm using only camera and I have permission to access it. @BenjaminZach